# Can I send POST request using http_load?

Tags: stress-testing

I want to do stress test on a API server using http_load. But I can only send GET request by default. Is POST request supported by http_load?

Answer (score 0):

http_load does not support POST method. You can use apache bench (`ab`) with -p parameter

`ab -T "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -p post_data_file.txt -n 1000 -c 32 http://localhost/`